# Compiling Eigen3 with only specific ops to reduce binary size

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, eigen3

I want to compile only the needed amount of ops in Eigen, I use only the basic matrix multiplications, component wise stuff and inverse, it seems like it could weigh way less, or no?

What should I do? Tried including only Eigen/Core and Eigen/LU, but it seems like I will have to write my own cmake file for it?

Comment: Eigen is a header-only template library. It doesn't compile any code that isn't called

Comment: Make sure you have optimization enabled (try `-O2`, or `-Os`). Also, you can disable assertions if you compile with `-DNDEBUG`.